# How to Use plugin RowEditing to Updating values

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I have a Grid panel and RowEditing Plugin. I search how to use events when i click on Update Button.

I can display alert() but i don't know how to retrieve updates datas ?!!

```
${prefix}grid.on('validateedit',onEdit, this);

function onEdit(e) {

          alert('UPDATE');
};
```

I have just one line on my Gridpanel. I need to retrieve all data to updating it :)!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onEdit` function, you receive the edit object (`e`), and you can access everything you need to from here.

For example, if I want to access the store... I can do so from within the `onEdit` function like

`var store = e.grid.store;`